# Can't link Python libraries inside C program

Tags: python, c, eclipse, linker-errors

I want to run a basic python script inside a C program using Eclipse. This is the code:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to link to several shared libraries like libpython2.7.so in Eclipse linker settings but I always get this error:

```
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -o "Test"  ./src/Test.o   -llibpython2.7
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -llibpython2.7
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't find any tutorial with the name of the lib that should be linked.

Comment: Typically `-l` doesn't require the `lib` prefix or the `.so` suffix... Have you tried `-lpython2.7`? Have you found the library on your system (does it exist)?

Comment: I tried -lpython2.7 and it works now, thank you !!! :)

Comment: ... I'm sure this is a duplicate, but please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically `-l` doesn't require the `lib` prefix or the `.so` suffix...

Try using `-lpython2.7` instead of `-llibpython2.7`.